# Jquery events inside dialog box

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I have a jquery dialog box what if is fired shows couple of input fields to be completed and to be submitted, inside I have a select drop down   what I would like to chain in function of the selected value to a text area in the meaning that the taxtarea should be filled with a custom text. My problems `how to declare a .change event inside of dialog?` `how to declare <textarea>$variable_text</textarea>`

what I tried

```
// Init Dialog
    $('a.open_dialog').click(function() {
        $('<div />').appendTo('body').load($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
            title: $(this).attr('title'),
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            width: 800,
            position: 'top'            
        });
        $('select#state').change(function() {
           // assign the value to a variable, so you can test to see if it is working
            var selectVal = $('select#state :selected').val();
            var emailMessage = 'lorem Ipsume dolores macus nacus';
            $("textarea#EmailMessage").val(emailMessage);
            alert( $("textarea#EmailMessage").val(emailMessage));
        });


        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really stated what isn't working.  One thing I can suggest is to modify how you extract the "selected" value of the dropdown element.

```
var selectVal = $('select#state').val();
```

There is no need to specify the "selected" option because a `<select>` element can only have one value. This is assuming of course that it is not a multi-select.

One more thing you might want to try, is to use the `on()` function instead of the `change()` function. If you are adding these elements dynamically to the document, the `change()` function might not fire because when the code is parsed, the element was not yet on the page.

```
$('select#state').on('change',function() {
  ...
});
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback, with .on my dialog box breaks. I'm getting back the raw html

Comment: Ok, if you use the regular `.change()` function, is it still executed even though the content is added dynamically?  If so, then you don't really *have* to use `on()`

Comment: with change won't break but I don't have any alerts on select

Comment: thanks for your help I have been upgrading my jquery ui and jquery and your tip works now.